# Scrolling using arrow keys not working in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, gatsby

I'm currently developing a React project using Gatsby in which the page is scrolled inside the main element, and the main element contains sections that snap on scroll (using the `scroll-snap-type`/`scroll-snap-align` properties in css). The structure of my site is as follows:

```html
<body>
  <div id="___gatsby">
    <div tabindex:"-1" id="gatsby-focus-wrapper" style="outline: none;">
      <main>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For some reason, having the page scroll inside the main element removes my ability to scroll using the arrow keys, and the issue seems to be with `#gatsby-focus-wrapper` which is added by @reach/router for accessibility reasons.

After some experimentation I found a hacky solution: removing the tab-index property from `#gatby-focus-wrapper` or setting `tabIndex: {-1}` on my main element. This allows me to scroll with the arrow keys after making the main element active by clicking the page, which isn't ideal but it's much better than not being able to use the arrow keys at all.

The following snippet demonstrates this same behaviour (you can't scroll with arrow keys without first clicking the page), but if you copy this code into a new Gatsby project (minus the gatsby wrapper elements of course) you won't be able to scroll using the arrow keys at all without using one of the methods I described above:

```css
html {
  height: calc(100vh - calc(100vh - 100%));
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body, #___gatsby, #gatsby-focus-wrapper, main {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.blue, .green, .yellow {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="___gatsby">
  <div id="gatsby-focus-wrapper" tabindex:"-1">
    <main>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the main element active by default to fix this? And if so would this break my site for screen readers? Or maybe some built in Gatsby functionality that I'm not taking advantage of?